# How do I modify the button configuration (buttonConfig) in angular ui.bootstrap.buttons module?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Looking at the angular-ui bootstrap code, I notice that a button config gets passed into the directive. The config defines the active class and toggle event. I'd like to modify those without modifying the angular-ui bootstrap code. How can I pass in my own configuration when using this directive?

Here is the code provided by angular-ui bootstrap:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.buttons', [])

  .constant('buttonConfig', {
    activeClass:'active',
    toggleEvent:'click'
  })

  .directive('btnRadio', ['buttonConfig', function (buttonConfig) {
  var activeClass = buttonConfig.activeClass || 'active';
  var toggleEvent = buttonConfig.toggleEvent || 'click';

  return {

    require:'ngModel',
    link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      var value = scope.$eval(attrs.btnRadio);

      //model -> UI
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
      }, function (modelValue) {
        if (angular.equals(modelValue, value)){
          element.addClass(activeClass);
        } else {
          element.removeClass(activeClass);
        }
      });

      //ui->model
      element.bind(toggleEvent, function () {
        if (!element.hasClass(activeClass)) {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(value);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple, just create a constant named `buttonConfig` in your application's module:

```
angular.module('myAppModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .constant('buttonConfig', {
    activeClass:'my-active-class'
  });
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hw5ahEos8UC5P23nV4oW?p=preview

Comment: I believe doing so will totally override the native constant, i.e. toggleEvent won't be defined anymore. Am I mistaken? If correct, it would be interesting to mention.